# How do you setup npm to install from a GitHub repository that uses Git LFS?

Tags: git

When I run `npm install --save git+ssh://git@github.com:bmahsman/bubblegum.git`, `npm` checks out the text files that `git lfs` puts in place of the actual assets. It appears `npm` isn't using my local user account's `~/.gitconfig`, i.e. the `lfs` filters aren't being used and `git-lfs` is not being called.

I verified that `git-lfs` and `git lfs` work from both `cmd` and `bash`. I tried the above `npm install` command in both `cmd` and `bash` and I get the same result. I verified that `git clone git@github.com:bmahsman/bubblegum.git` from scratch produces the actual binary files instead of the text files.

My repo is located at `https://github.com/bmahsman/bubblegum` and I use Git LFS to manage binary art and sound assets, so it has a `.gitattributes` modified with `git lfs track`:

```
$ cat ./.gitattributes
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogv filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

My local user account is configured for `git` this way:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = Brynn Mahsman
    email = brynn.mahsman@gmail.com
[merge]
    ff = no
[credential]
    helper = cache
[alias]
    sc = git clone --recursive
    sp = push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
    su = submodule update --remote --merge
[push]
    default = simple
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
```

I'm using Windows 7.

```
$ npm -v
2.14.7

$ git --version
git version 2.6.2.windows.1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for moving this. I wasn't sure if it should go on Stack Overflow since it wasn't necessarily programming.